# Riverpod: Implementing an infinite loading provider the right way

Tags: flutter, riverpod

As a Provider user I've always wondered about using Riverpod since they're from the same author. I've been playing around with it and like the use of `with()` but I'm having problems implementing an infinite loading scroll in my test environment.

I'm pretty sure I'm thinking about this the wrong way but there are some things I find confusing. I'm able to load my first data correctly but loading any succeeding pages from there won't work. These 3 things come to mind:

- In `fetchNextBatch()`, what's the right way to append to state?
- What's the right way to check for loading status to prevent multiple fetches?
- I'm using `page` as an attribute of `RecipeData` but should this be a `StateProvider<int>` instead? Will it cause problems with rebuilds?

I realize this is a rundown topic that's already been discussed at length but this is just me kicking the wheels trying to get a firm grip on its features.

#### My RecipeData provider

```dart
@riverpod
class RecipeData extends _$RecipeData {
  int page = 1;
  final int _limit = 8;

  @override
  Future<List<Recipe>> build() async {
    final int offset = (page - 1) * _limit;
    final List<Recipe> data = await RecipeService.fetchFromApi(ref, _limit, offset);
    return data;
  }

  Future<List<Recipe>> fetchNextBatch() async {

    // TODO: Don't fetch if another fetch is in progress

    incrPage();
    final int offset = (page - 1) * _limit;
    final awaiteddata = await RecipeService.fetchFromApi(ref, _limit, offset);

    // Why is this wrong?
    state = [...state, ...awaiteddata];
  } 

  void incrPage() => page++;

  void resetPage() => page = 0;
}
```

#### Widget

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final recipes = ref.watch(recipeDataProvider);

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Playground')
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        ...
        // when() is great
        recipes.when(
          data: (data) => ListView.builder(...),
          loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          error: (err, _) => Text(err.toString()),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

#### Related code

##### Basic Recipe model

```dart
@freezed
class Recipe with _$Recipe {
  const factory Recipe({
    required String name,
    required String cuisine,
    required String image,
  }) = _Recipe;

  factory Recipe.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) => _$RecipeFromJson(json);
}
```

I also created this in case I needed it which is just another provider that has `alldata` and `page` in it.

```dart
@freezed
class RecipeResponse with _$RecipeResponse {
  const factory RecipeResponse({
    @Default([]) final List<Recipe> alldata,
    @Default(1) final int page,
  }) = _RecipeResponse;
}
```

Comment: I'm study riverpod too.
Does your code working?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. I'm getting the error `type 'AsyncData<List<Product>> is not a subtype of type List<Product>` after adding `(state as List<Product>).addAll(awaiteddata);`

Answer (score 0):

in your case

```
Future<void> fetchNextBatch() async {

  incrPage();
  final int offset = (page - 1) * _limit;
  final awaiteddata = await RecipeService.fetchFromApi(ref, _limit, offset);
  final previousState = await future;
  state = AsyncData([...previousState, ...awaiteddata]);
}
```

there is my sample

```
enum ProductFilterEnum {
  onSale,
  review,
  reject,
  notSale,
}

//filter state
@riverpod
class ProductFilter extends _$ProductFilter {
  @override
  ProductFilterEnum build() {
    return ProductFilterEnum.onSale;
  }
}

//search state
@riverpod
class ProductSearch extends _$ProductSearch {
  @override
  String build() {
    return "";
  }
}

//sort state
@riverpod
class ProductSort extends _$ProductSort {
  @override
  bool build() {
    return false;
  }
}

@riverpod
class Product extends _$Product {
  int _page = 0;

  @override
  Future<List<ProducModel>> build() async {
    final result = await fetch(_page);
    return result;
  }

  Future<void> getNextPage() async {
    _page++;
    final result = await fetch(_page);
    final previousState = await future;
    state = AsyncData([...previousState, ...result]);
  }

  //api
  Future<List<ProducModel>> fetch(int page) async {
    final filter = ref.watch(productFilterProvider);
    final search = ref.watch(productSearchProvider);
    final sort = ref.watch(productSortProvider);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    return [ProducModel(name: "$page $search $filter")];
  }
}
```

in widget

```
//watch for change
Widget tabBarView() {
  final providerList = ref.watch(productProvider);
  final search = ref.watch(productSearchProvider);
  final list = providerList.value ?? [];
  if (providerList.isLoading) {
    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
  //when search empty
  if (search.isNotEmpty && list.isEmpty) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        AppLocalizations.of(context)!.translate('product_search_empty'),
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, color: AppStyle.grayColor2, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
      ),
    );
  }
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final item = list[index];
      return listItem(item);
    },
  );
}


//tabBarView will change after read
Textfield(
  controller: _search,
  onEditingComplete: () {
    ref.read(productSearchProvider.notifier).state = _search.text;
  },
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
),
```